# Login credentials for nodes in MaaS node list after obtaining deployed state

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have a total of three machines. I have installed MaaS in one of my machines and the other two machines were added to the MaaS nodes list and kept in ready state.

When I run the fourth step given in the [Installing The Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu OpenStack](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) Ubuntu documentation, both the machines went to the deployed state.

Both the nodes in the deployed state are asking for login and password, and the Ubuntu OpenStack installer screen is running for too long a time. I don't know to how to proceed. Please help me. I am looking for this to do simple job scheduling in a cloud environment using OpenStack.

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh to each node as ubuntu@ip using the ssh-rsa key you installed or generated during setup of MaaS